# Datagridview Headers Selection

Tags: c#, datagridview, controls

I have a DataGridView With 5 columns, when a user selects on any of the headers, i want to get the column Index that was selected, but i seem to be getting the current cell that's selected.

```cs
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

   //The e.RowIndex returns a -1 every time **`strong text`**
   // dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Selected = true;

    var cellId = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

    string column = dataGridView1.Columns[cellId].HeaderText;

    if (column == "Description")
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = notifications.OrderBy(a => a.Description).ToList();
    }
    else if (column == "Category")
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = notifications.OrderBy(a => a.Category).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Granted when the user clicks on a column header, `e.RowIndex` is going to return a -1, however `e.ColumnIndex` should return the selected column index so it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `e.ColumnIndex` to get the selected ColumnIndex

```
 string column = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
```